Composable not triggering recomposition
so the issue I'm facing is that when I update a MutableStateFlow value in my ViewModel, the value does not update in the composable:
ViewModel:
private val _dummyData = MutableStateFlow(DummyData())
val dummyData = _dummyData.asStateFlow()

init {
    // Grab the latest data. I've tried grabbing this from onResume() in fragment as well.
    getDummyData()
}

private fun getDummyData() {
    myService.grabData { data ->
        val list = mutableStateListOf<Dummy>()
        data.forEach {
            list.add(it)
        }

        val dummy = DummyData(
            list = list,
        )

        _dummyData.tryEmit(dummy)
    }
}

DummyData:
data class DummyData(
    val list: SnapshotStateList<Dummy> = mutableStateListOf(),
    // View visibility is conditional, based on various factors, adding this here to
    //  show the reason why I'm using it like this
    val displayView: Boolean = false,
)

data class Dummy(val message: String, val url: String)

Fragment:
val dummyData by viewModel.dummyData.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

// Pass data into composable function

Composable:
LazyRow(
    state = rememberLazyListState(),
    modifier = Modifier,
) {
    // Display list of objects here, they only display on first load.
    // So when I add some break points, I can see the value getting updated in the
    // viewModel, but the change never gets updated here when I change to a different
    // fragment and then navigate back
    val data = dummyData.list
    items(data) { item ->
        // do some stuff, but not relevant to the question, breakpoint at the items(data)
        // to view value of the data, and see that it never gets updated
    }
}


There were several compile errors in your code that I fixed. Please verify that it is still what you wanted to ask.

Hey, thanks, yep, the question remains the same and is expressed as such after your edits :)

_dummyData.update { dummy} try this better and thread safe. and it this val dummyData by viewModel.dummyData.collectAsStateWithLifecycle() in compose ui?

do you really need     val list: SnapshotStateList<Dummy> = mutableStateListOf() can you just not have a immutable list?

I need to be able to modify the list contents depending on the users actions. Like remove values etc. Also, used update{ dummy.copy... } initially, but had similar results. And yes, the val dummyData by viewModel.dummyData.collectAsStateWithLifecycle() is in compose UI - android studio would freak out a tad otherwise :P

This is a massive mind boggle of an issue for me at the moment

And well, technically, if another type will work then I'd use that instead. Have tried with normal arraylist() with similar results. Some stack posts suggested using SnapshotStateList(), but the result remains the same

ok.  myService.grabData { data -> not sure what is this, but can you put a break point at _dummyData.tryEmit(dummy) and see if this gets updated?

Had a quick look, the viewModel code runs + updates, but then never pops the composable

You need to make DummyData and its properties immutable, otherwise it won't work with StateFlows.
That means the list property must be declared like this:
val list: List<Dummy> = emptyList()

If you want to change the list you need to create a new DummyData object with a new list. For example, adding a new element would then look like this:
_dummyData.update {
    it.copy(
        list = it.list + Dummy(...)
    )
}


hmm. copy i missed this in review.

Tried, so the var updates as expected, did use this approach as well. Problem is that the update does not get pushed to the composable, thats why I started using different var types etc

Marking this as the answer, solution ended up being something rather unrelated. Did however revert to using update + copy, better approach by far. Problem was the service that got the data was creating some issues. My bad, thought that would not affect this. TIL
